# Group by one column and check for value in another column in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, countif

Here is my original df:

```
my_df_1 <- data.frame(col_1 = c(rep('a',5), rep('b',5), rep('c', 5)),
                    col_2 = c(rep('x',3), rep('y', 9), rep('x', 3)))
```

I would like to group by `col_1` and return 1 if `col_2` for given group contains `x`, and 0 if not.

Here is how final result is supposed to look:

```
my_df_2 <- data.frame(col_1 = c(rep('a',5), rep('b',5), rep('c', 5)),
                col_2 = c(rep('x',3), rep('y', 9), rep('x', 3)), 
                col_3 = c(rep(1,5), rep(0,5), rep(1, 5)))
```

I would prefer to get it done with `dplyr`, if possible. This is kind of `count if` predicate, but cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of doing it, it would also be robust if your `col_2` contains `x` in combination with other characters/numbers (e.g. `xa`, `x7`, or similar):

```
library(dplyr)

my_df_1 %>%
  group_by(col_1) %>%
  mutate(col_3 = ifelse(any(grepl("x", col_2)), 1, 0))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   col_1 [3]
   col_1 col_2 col_3
   <fct> <fct> <dbl>
 1 a     x         1
 2 a     x         1
 3 a     x         1
 4 a     y         1
 5 a     y         1
 6 b     y         0
 7 b     y         0
 8 b     y         0
 9 b     y         0
10 b     y         0
11 c     y         1
12 c     y         1
13 c     x         1
14 c     x         1
15 c     x         1
```

Answer (score 3):

As we are looking for whether there is 'x' `%in%` the 'col2' for each unique element of 'col_1', after grouping by 'col_1', get the logical vector of length 1 with `%in%` (by placing "x" on the lhs of the %in%) and convert it to binary with `as.integer`

```
library(dplyr)
my_df_1 %>% 
   group_by(col_1) %>% 
   mutate(col_3 = as.integer("x" %in% col_2))
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   col_1 [3]
#   col_1 col_2 col_3
#   <fct> <fct> <int>
# 1 a     x         1
# 2 a     x         1
# 3 a     x         1
# 4 a     y         1
# 5 a     y         1
# 6 b     y         0
# 7 b     y         0
# 8 b     y         0
# 9 b     y         0
#10 b     y         0
#11 c     y         1
#12 c     y         1
#13 c     x         1
#14 c     x         1
#15 c     x         1
```

---

If the 'x' is only a partial match, then use `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
my_df_1 %>%
    group_by(col_1) %>%
    mutate(col_3 = +(any(str_detect(col_2, "x"))))
```

Comment: Wow, this is some solid understanding of R! I wish I could accept both answers.

Comment: Knew about turning into `integer` but not about `+`, cool hack!